# Eclipse Java Maven Project Java file which is not on a build path

Tags: eclipse, maven

I met a problem: 
when I double click java files in a Maven project the JDT icon tells its not on a build path, 
and if I double click java files in normal project it would be normal and I can use ctrl+click to trace the declaration of classes. 
How do I set the build path right for those java files in Maven projects?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In maven projects, all the files inside the folders `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` are in the build path. Usually, there is no need to change that. You should use other folders only in special cases.

Comment: Thanks, after read your answer I noticed that I should import it as Maven project and it can recognize the classes now!